# only want to have unique pairs

Tags: python, list, tuples

so I have this list which has multiple tuples in it tuples contain stock names from Indian stock market so the way I am using these tuples like stock pairs but problem is  I don't want to repeat a tuple but in this list there are multiple tuples which are replicated but in reverse manner like ('ALBK', 'SBIN') same ('SBIN', 'ALBK') I only want one of these .ex ('ANDHRABANK', 'INDIANB') is also repeated as ('INDIANB', 'ANDHRABANK') I want to delete the replicate tuples how to do that

```
pairs = [('ALBK', 'SBIN'), ('ANDHRABANK', 'INDIANB'), ('ANDHRABANK', 'SBIN'), ('AXISBANK', 'FEDERALBNK'), 
 ('AXISBANK', 'INDIANB'), ('BANKBARODA', 'FEDERALBNK'), ('BANKINDIA', 'AXISBANK'), ('FEDERALBNK', 'AXISBANK'), 
 ('FEDERALBNK', 'BANKBARODA'), ('FEDERALBNK', 'UNIONBANK'), ('HDFC', 'ICICIBANK'), ('ICICIBANK', 'FEDERALBNK'), 
 ('ICICIBANK', 'HDFC'), ('ICICIBANK', 'INDIANB'), ('INDIANB', 'ANDHRABANK'), ('INDIANB', 'AXISBANK'), ('INDIANB', 'ICICIBANK'),
 ('SBIN', 'ALBK'), ('SBIN', 'ANDHRABANK'), ('UNIONBANK', 'FEDERALBNK')]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: You could store the pairs as sets instead of tuples, which would automatically remove duplicates.

Comment: I think this problem does not match the one marked as duplicate. Here we don't simply want to remove duplicates, but instead, two elements can be treated as *the same* in spite of not being strictly equal (different order)

Comment: @Prune The duplicate you linked to only removes exactly duplicates, not when they're tuples in different orders.

Answer (score 3):

Sort the pairs and put them in a `set`.

```
unique_pairs = set(tuple(sorted(p)) for p in pairs)
```

Since `set` elements have to be unique, this will remove the duplicates.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/pFglrb)

Comment: The return value of `sorted(some_list)` is a list, which can't be hashed by `set()`

Comment: I assumed `sorted(some_tuple)` would return a tuple, I see I was wrong.

Comment: @josoler I changed it to convert the sorted tuples back to tuples.

Answer (score 0):

just check like so:

```py
nonDupPairs = []
for i in pairs:
    if i[::-1] not in nonDupPairs:
        nonDupPairs.append(i)
```

That should work

Comment: If there are duplicates that have the *same* order this will add both of them to the result.

Comment: okay I get it. So he also wants to remove them if they are not the same order

Comment: Exactly. **there are multiple tuples which are replicated but in reverse manner like ('ALBK', 'SBIN') same ('SBIN', 'ALBK') I only want one of these**